# In Unity, reordering child game objects randomly

Tags: unity-game-engine, random

I am making a board game. There is a grid. Grid has many tiles. [Board image.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sfzHN.jpg)
Tiles are child game objects of grid. I want to reorder tiles randomly at the end of each level.

```
    foreach (GameObject tile in tileList)
    {
        tile.transform.SetSiblingIndex(UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, tileCount));
    }
```

I tried like this. Is this snippet of code correct?

All items are UI element. They aren't sprite.
[Grid has grid layout group component.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ncRne.jpg) Positions of tiles are automatically assigned by grid.

Comment: no, you might end up with multiple objects with the same sibling index

Comment: @Jimmar no that's not true .. If you assign two objects the same index it will just move the following children one index higher .. kind of similar to what `InsertAt` in a list would do

Comment: `Is this snippet of code correct?` .. well does it do what you want to achieve?

Comment: @derHugo Sometimes the correct answer tiles are very close to each other.

Comment: @FxGames well .. random is random so yes this might happen from time to time ;) .. there is a huge difference between randomness and equaly spreading ... there might occur clusters in random patterns

Answer (score 1):

```
public void Demo()
    {
        Fun1 ();
        //Fun2 ();
    }

    public void Fun1 ()
    {
        // remove group children
        removeChildren ();
        //sort List
        tileList.Sort (sortList);
        GameObject parent = new GameObject();
        foreach ( GameObject tile in tileList )
        {
            tile.transform.SetParent (parent);
        }
    }

    private int sortList (int a , int b)
    {
        return a - b;
    }

    public void Fun2()
    {
        foreach ( GameObject tile in tileList )
        {
            tile.transform.SetSiblingIndex (UnityEngine.Random.Range (0 , tileCount));
        }
        LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate (GameObject.GetComponent<RectTransform>());
    }
```

you can test LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate see see.

Answer (score -1):

Setting the sibbling index wont move the tiles. What you can is a quick [shuffle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/273313/randomize-a-listt). like you would to randomize a list.

```
 public void ShuffleBoard()
{        
    int n = tileList.Count;
    while (n > 1)
    {
        n--;
        int k = UnityEngine.Random.Range(0, n + 1);
        Tile value = tileList[k];
        tileList[k] = tileList[n];
        tileList[n] = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: Well this shuffles the list ..  but it will even less move any tiles ^^